# Signing ASP.NET 5 Class Library Assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The output of an ASP.NET 5 Class Library Project is a Nuget Package (.nupkg) containing the full .NET and DNX Core assemblies.

I wish to distribute the NuGet package to third party developers. The new ASP.NET 5 Class Library Project does not have an option to sign the compiled assemblies. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at this [repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Signing). I guess this is not ready yet, but at least you can get some understanding how this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are targeting full .Net Framework you can sign assemblies with strong name by setting the `"keyFile" : "c:\\keyfile.snk"` property in the compilation options in your project.json file. Note however that Core Clr does not support real strong naming. Rather it supports signing with just a public key. If you want to go this route you would use `"strongName" : true` in compilation options. For more details see [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2157) on github.

**EDIT**

Things have changed in RC1. One of the bigger changes/improvements is the ability to OSS sign assemblies using .snk files. You can find all the details in [my post on signing assemblies in ASP.NET 5](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/15/creating-and-using-strong-named-assemblies-in-asp-net-5/). With the merger of dotnet and dnx (think: ASP.NET Core 1) things will evolve even more in RC2 and beyond. I think one of the biggest immediate changes will be that you no longer will be able to OSS sign assemblies without .snk.

Comment: Can I use both? So proper signing for full CLR and public key signing with Core CLR?

Comment: Not at the moment. I filed an issue for that: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2206

Comment: So it turned out that you actually can use both. I thought that CoreClr assemblies cannot be real strong named but they can so it is only about what runtime you are using to run the compiler. With CoreClr you can only fake strong name assemblies with FullClr you can sign with real strong names.

Comment: Ok cool, so we can use ```keyFile``` on its own? Secondly, what do you pass to ```keyFile``` if you have a single shared .snk at the root of your solution? I tried some slashes but I get errors.

Comment: This works on my box `"compilationOptions": { "keyFile": "../../../Key.snk"},`. One important thing - you need to be on beta6 unstable bits.